# How to make this asynchronous code run inside of this for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, synchronization

I have a for..of loop with a .then inside it. The .then has been my last resort, I have tried promiseAll and a just simple promises but I just cannot get this to work. (To clarify: It needs to loop through the all1 array **in order**

```
let all1 = await VCLB.findAll({order: [['time', 'DESC']], limit: 10});
  let list1 = [];
  let q = 0;
for(item of all1) {
    if(!message.guild.members.get(item.id)) return;
    if(item.time == 0) return;
          let time = item.time
    VC.findOne({where: {id: item.id}}).then(findVC => {
      if(!findVC) return;
        let timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        let startVC = findVC.time;
        let difference = timeNow - startVC;
        time = time + difference;

    })
    q++;
    time = prettyMilliseconds(time)
    list1.push(`**${q}.** | ${message.guild.members.get(item.id)} | **${time}** `)

  }
```

The part that isn't working is the

```
    VC.findOne({where: {id: item.id}}).then(findVC => {
      if(!findVC) return;
        let timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        let startVC = findVC.time;
        let difference = timeNow - startVC;
        time = time + difference;

    })
```

as even if it finds something there, it doesn't update the time variable. I know there is no way this .then() could work, but I honestly have no other clue on how I can do this without some type of async. This code has to be sync as after the data is gathered it puts it all into a singular string. Before I was trying to use await to await a database search, but obviously in this circumstance that isn't possible as I need to wait for the data to first be gathered. Any solution which allows the database to be searched before continuing is fine.

Thanks a lot
Sam

Comment: This kind of problem is quite an easy one to try reproduce as a _minimal_ example, using setTimeout, and then you can remove all of the cruft. Quite often, creating the minimal production helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Make your function `async` and just call everything in order without having to worry about all the `.then()`'s

Comment: `let findVC = await VC.findOne( .... );` .... etc?